# How to get the last non null value from the MYSQL table with the LAG

Tags: mysql, null, lag

I'm tying a LAG function to retrieve the last non null value from the table to replace the null values in a row.
The code I'm using:

```
SELECT ticket_id, business_area, priority ,client_name, 
        closed_date, closed_date_id,Next_Create_date, 
        case 
            when Next_Create_date is null and Ticket_ID = 0 
            then LAG(Next_Create_date) 
                over (partition by ticket_id, business_area, 
                            priority, client_name, 
                            closed_date, Closed_Date_ID 
                        order by Next_Create_date desc 
                     ) 
            else Next_Create_date 
        end  Next_Create_date2
from ams_auto.No_Issue_Time_NM a
order by closed_date desc ;
```

And these are the results:

[image]

Every yellow Next_Created_Date2 field should really have the last NON null value. In this case that would be '2021-07-16 00:44:17' but for some reason it's not working.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Sample data:

| ticket_id | business_area | priority | client_name | closed_date | Next_Create_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61622 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 7/22/2021 22:49 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 7/19/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 7/19/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 7/12/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 7/12/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 7/12/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 7/5/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 7/5/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 7/5/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 6/28/2021 2:00 | null |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 6/28/2021 2:00 | null |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 6/28/2021 2:00 | null |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 6/21/2021 2:00 | null |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 6/21/2021 2:00 | null |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 6/21/2021 2:00 | null |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 6/14/2021 2:00 | null |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 6/14/2021 2:00 | null |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 6/14/2021 2:00 | null |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 6/7/2021 2:00 | null |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 6/7/2021 2:00 | null |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 6/7/2021 2:00 | null |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 5/31/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 5/31/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 5/31/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 57765 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 5/28/2021 2:35 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 57615 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 5/27/2021 2:24 | 5/28/2021 0:56 |

And this is the desired result:

| ticket_id | business_area | priority | client_name | closed_date | Next_Create_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61622 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 7/22/2021 22:49 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 7/19/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 7/19/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 7/12/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 7/12/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 7/12/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 7/5/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 7/5/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 7/5/2021 2:00 | 8/29/2021 0:46 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 6/28/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 6/28/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 6/28/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 6/21/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 6/21/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 6/21/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 6/14/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 6/14/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 6/14/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 6/7/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 6/7/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 6/7/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 1 | TB | 5/31/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 2 | TB | 5/31/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 0 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 5/31/2021 2:00 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 57765 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 5/28/2021 2:35 | 7/16/2021 0:44 |
| 57615 | RMS | Severity 3 | TB | 5/27/2021 2:24 | 5/28/2021 0:56 |

Kind regards,
Rosa

Comment: Provide some sample data as textual formatted code (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 5-10 rows), and show desired output for this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any test data to play with, so here is an simple example

```
with qq(q) as (
  select 1 union all
  select 2 union all
  select null union all
  select 3
)

select q, 
       lag(q, 1, 'nothing to show') over(order by q desc)
  from qq;
```

You may sort data and move nulls in the end - just sort it descending (don't ask me why).

Here is the result

| q | lag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | nothing to show |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
|  | 3 |

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jj2qsWCt7hsXteVEDHnfUm/2) to play with

UPD. For the test case uploaded there is no need to use LAG but you may find subqueries useful here

```
select td.ticket_id,
       td.business_area,
       td.priority,
       td.client_name,
       td.closed_date,
       ifnull(td.next_create_date, (select min(next_create_date) 
                                      from test_data td_1
                                     where td_1.ticket_id = td.ticket_id
                                       and td_1.business_area = td.business_area
                                       and td_1.priority = td.priority
                                       and td_1.client_name = td.client_name
                                       and td_1.next_create_date > td.closed_date) 
             ) next_creation_date_fixed
  from test_data td
 order by closed_date desc;
```

One thing to mention is subqueries often lead to performance degradataion, so if you're on mySQL >= 8.0.14 you may find lateral joins useful.
See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) for details

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gjM1saV2jkoaFthsi22NHm/0)

Comment: *There is a hidden feature in MySQL how to sort data and **move nulls in the end*** No, NULLS are always placed on the top for ASC and on the bottom for DESC. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jj2qsWCt7hsXteVEDHnfUm/1

Comment: @Akina Hmm you're right, I was somehow sure it works only that way. Updated my answer. Спасибо!

Comment: *don't ask me why* This is simple. Compare with NULL gives NULL (Unknown), and in sorting process too. But the sorting cannot use ternary logic - either swap or not, no third variant. And the sorting assumes that NULL is the most least value.

Comment: What meant was "don't ask me why the sorting assumes that NULL is the most least value". For example, Oracle assumes the opposite (don't ask me why too :) )

Comment: Hi @ekochergin, I tried adding it in tabluar way, it looks good in preview and then when I post it it looses format.

Comment: Hi @RosaNegra you missed the emty line before table. I'll check up with you a bit later

Comment: Hi @ekochergin, the tabular looks good now. So, I need to replace the null value with the last non null value from records before.

Comment: @RosaNegra sorry it is not clear to me what logic is here. There are too many identical timestamps protocolled and this all is confusing. Can you perhaps get a simplified example with less data and more clear explantion?

Comment: @ekochergin, the records are not the same. you will notice that the tickets with id 0 and certain priority have null values for the monday of the week. I just need to populate the values between 2021-06-07 until 2021-07-05 with the maximum value from before that date (2021-06-07) .

Comment: Thank you @ekochergin! this solved the problem!

Comment: @RosaNegra always welcome